# dateDecodingStrategy shows an incorrect year

Tags: swift

I use `dateDecodingStrategy` from this form of data in the API : `1537547954.916`.

Here is my code:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970 
do {
    let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(weather.self, from: data!)
    completion(.success(json.content))
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

The year of the data is `2018`, but it pass `2049`.

Comment: I did but nothing change, is it wired, yes?

Comment: When I try: let aDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1537547954.916), I get "Sep 21, 2018 at 6:39 PM". Where do you get 2049 ?
Could you post more code, so that one can test (weather ? data ?, completion ?)

Comment: It is Swift convention to name all your classes and structures starting with an uppercase letter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I use dateDecodingStrategy

No, you don't. You are using two different instances of `JSONDecoder`, the second doesn't consider the date decoding strategy.

And – as mentioned in the comments – please name structs with starting capital letter

```
struct Weather : Decodable { ... }
```

---

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970 
do {
    let json = try decoder.decode(Weather.self, from: data!)
    completion(.success(json.content))
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Please note the subtle but crucial difference

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and others. I appreciate it